# contextmenustrip: check selected item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a contextmenustrip that contains some option, I have almost implemented everything, i just want to check which items i have selected in options_MouseClick

```
  private void ConsoleRichTextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            options.Show();
            Point currentPoint;
            currentPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            options.Show(ConsoleRichTextBox, currentPoint);
        }

    }

    private void options_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         //if options selected = clear
        ConsoleRichTextBox.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: put a breakpoint inside the method options_MouseClick and inspect with the debugger (mouse over and expand the small crossed) the type and value of sender and the properties of the MouseEventArgs e. Found anything interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just handle the Click event of each of the menu items. There's no need to handle the MouseClick event of a contextmenustrip. Also you can add multiple handlers to the same method and differentiate with the sender parameter as this will refer to the exact menu item that was clicked.

```
        ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        tsmi.Click += tsmi_Click;
```

and:

```
    public void tsmi_Click(object sender, EventArgs  e)
    {
        if (sender == tsmi)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```